# How do you dynamically change the id of an element in Angular?

Tags: angular, element

I have an element in a loop and I just want to change it's id so as to avoid conflicts. I did some searching, but can't seem to find anything.

```
<div *ngFor="let location of job.tasks; let i = index">
  <div id="index-{{i}}">
    {{index}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I call in ngOnInit `document.getElementById('index-1')` it returns null because it hasn't assigned the id yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate `ngFor` index(`i`) inside `id` attribute.

```
<div *ngFor="let location of job.tasks; let i = index">
  <div id="index-{{i}}">
    {{index}}
  </div>
</div>
```

You should query your DOM `ngFor` looping over, you can do the same inside `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle event

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('1'));
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dFy18Z0hObzCWfsad70A?p=preview)

---

More right way to do this using `#template-variable` on `ngFor` template and `@ViewChildren` decorator to find out respective DOM.

Comment: That worked, but I realize the problem isn't what I thought. I've updated my question to reflect my error.